# How do I dynamically join a socket.io namespace in react with multiplexing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, socket.io

I'm currently trying to build a simple multiplayer game. Each game instance is within its own namespace and gets created via a high order function:

```js
const createNamespace = (io: InitServer, gameCode: string): GameNamespace => {
    let code: string = gameCode
    const namespace: GameNameSpace = io.of(code)
    let gameInstance: Game | null = new Game(namespace, code)
    
    namespace.use((socket: GameServerSocket, next) => {
        //Do some authentification
        next()
    })
    
    namespace.on('connection', (socket: GameServerSocket) => {
        console.log(`[${code}] A player connected: ${socket.id}`)
    
        socket.onAny((event, ...args) => {
            console.log(`[${code}] Got ${event} with args ${args}`)
        })
    })
    
    const clearNamespace = () => {
        namespace.sockets.forEach(socket => {
            socket.disconnect()
        })
        let remainingListeners = namespace.eventNames()
        namespace.removeAllListeners()
        remainingListeners = namespace.eventNames()
        if (remainingListeners.length === 0) {
            console.log('All event listeners removed successfully.')
        } else {
            console.log('There are remaining event listeners:', remainingListeners)
        }
        gameInstance = null
        // @ts-ignore
        code = null
        // Remove the namespace from io._nsps
        if (io._nsps.has(namespace.name)) {
            io._nsps.delete(namespace.name)
            console.log('Namespace removed successfully.')
        } else {
            console.log('Namespace was not found in io._nsps.')
        }
    
    }
    
    return {
        gameInstance,
        namespace,
        code,
        clearNamespace,
    }

}

export default createNamespace
```

In the Middleware I check a JWT Token which is successfully generated, sent to the client and received. It also includes the socket.id. Though when the middleware checks the token the socket.id in the token and the socket.id provided do not match anymore.

In React I created a socket.ts to create the default socket and a function to "join" a namespace:

```js
export const socket: LobbySocket = io(URL, {
    autoConnect: true,
})

export const createNamespaceSocket = (namespace: string): GameNamespaceSocket => {
    return io(`${URL}/${namespace}`, {
        autoConnect: true,
        query: { token: JWTManager.getToken() },
    }) as GameNamespaceSocket
}
```

The socket is called in the main component to handle the jwt authentication and joining a game.
A gameComponent receives the "gameCode" and tries to join the namespace with given gameCode string.

This is resulting in the creation of another socket trying to join the namespace, which of course doesn't work, since my authentication middleware is checking for the socketId to match the one provided via the jwt.

The [socket.io documentation](https://socket.io/docs/v4/namespaces/#client-initialization) states

> [...]only one WebSocket connection will be established, and the packets will automatically be routed to the right namespace.

What did I do wrong? How can I fix this?